# Include my html code inside content of email in sendgrid emai

Tags: php, html, sendgrid

I have made separate html file and using file_get_content i am using it to  include it in my content part but when i recieve email html code is displayed as a text rather than what the ouptut of html file should be

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<div class="popup-logo" style="width: 100px;">
<img src="logo.png" alt="jk" style="margin-left: 45%;width: 200px;height: 50px;"></div>
</div>
    <div id="popup" style="width: 100%;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;background: #FFFFFF;-moz-box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;-webkit-box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;margin-top: 1%;">
 
  <div class="search-col" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;float: left;margin-bottom: 5px;padding: .2px;width: 100%;table, th, td {
    border: .5px solid silver;border-collapse: collapse;">

  
        
 <div class="select-style">
     <div class="select-style-text" style="width: 100%;height: 67px;float: left;padding-left: 10px;">
                 <p style="color: #840107;font-family: Hind;font-size: 25px;font-weight: 600;text-align: left;margin-left: 40%;text-overflow: none;text-indent: 2em;">Dispatched Details</p>
     
     </div>
      <div class="da" style="color:green;margin-left:85%;">
     <?php 
    
     $date = date('d-M-Y H:i:s');
     echo "Date"."&nbsp;". $date;
     ?>
     </div>
     
</div>
 
     
    </div>

<div>

<div id="wer">

<h3 style="padding: 0.5px;padding-left: 5px;">Order Number:<?php echo $_SESSION['id'];?></h3>
<h3 style="padding: 0.5px;padding-left: 5px;">Vendor details:</h3>
<div id="wer" style="margin-left:0%;">
<table style="width: 100%;border: 1px solid silver;border-collapse: collapse;text-align: center;">
  <tr>
  <th style="border: 1px solid silver;border-collapse: collapse;text-align: center;">VendorName</th>
    <th style="border: 1px solid silver;border-collapse: collapse;text-align: center;">Code</th>
    <th style="border: 1px solid silver;border-collapse: collapse;text-align: center;">Email</th>
 <th style="border: 1px solid silver;border-collapse: collapse;text-align: center;">Contact</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid silver;border-collapse: collapse;text-align: center;"><?php echo $_SESSION['vnm']?></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid silver;border-collapse: collapse;text-align: center;"><?php echo $_SESSION['vcd']?></td>
 <td style="border: 1px solid silver;border-collapse: collapse;text-align: center;"><?php echo $_SESSION['vem']?></td>
 <td style="border: 1px solid silver;border-collapse: collapse;text-align: center;"><?php echo $_SESSION['vcn']?></td>

  </tr>
 
  
</table>
</div>

<div id="wer" style="margin-top:3%;">

<h3 style="padding: 0.5px;padding-left: 5px;">Other Details:</h3>
<style>

</style>
<table style="width: 100%;border: 1px solid silver;border-collapse: collapse;text-align: center;">
  <tr>
    <th style="border: 1px solid silver;border-collapse: collapse;text-align: center;">Driver name</th>
    <th style="border: 1px solid silver;border-collapse: collapse;text-align: center;">Driver contact </th>
 <th style="border: 1px solid silver;border-collapse: collapse;text-align: center;">Vehicle Number</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid silver;border-collapse: collapse;text-align: center;"><?php echo $_SESSION['drivname']?></td>
 <td style="border: 1px solid silver;border-collapse: collapse;text-align: center;"><?php echo $_SESSION['dcontact']?></td>
 <td style="border: 1px solid silver;border-collapse: collapse;text-align: center;"><?php echo $_SESSION['vnumber']?></td>

  </tr>
 
  
</table>
</div>
<?php session_destroy();?>
</div></div></div></body>
</html>
```

```
<?php
require '/sendgrid-php/vendor/autoload.php';

if(require("sendgrid-php/vendor/autoload.php"))
    {echo "path found";}

$from = new SendGrid\Email(null, 'k1@gmail.com');
$subject ='Order number is'; 
$to = new SendGrid\Email(null, 'k2@gmail.com');
$r=file_get_contents('ret.html');
$content = new SendGrid\Content("text/plain",$r);
$mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);
$apiKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);

$response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
echo $response->statusCode();
echo $response->headers();
echo $response->body();
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include that file, evaluate it as PHP and capture it inside a variable instead of storing the unevaluated content in a string:

```
ob_start();
include("ret.html");
$r = ob_get_clean();
$content = new SendGrid\Content("text/html",$r);
```

By the way, you should consider using a templating engine for that job.

Comment: Still i am receiving plain text @Tacsiazuma

Comment: Edited the content type to text/html

Comment: Template engine ill find more about them @Tacsiazuma

Answer (score 2):

From what I can understand, your email is sent as plain text instead of an html. That's because you have the email type set as `text/plain` when creating the SendGrid object. Changing it to `text/html` should do it. Replace this line

```
$content = new SendGrid\Content("text/plain",$r);
```

with

```
$content = new SendGrid\Content("text/html",$r);
```